# Curly bracket is displayed wrong

Tags: listings

I'm trying to use the package `lstlisting` and most of the code is displayed correct.

But the character `_` , `{` and `}` are replaced with other characters. The character `_` is replaced with `"`, `{` is replaced with `-` and so on.

Do you have any idea what's going wrong?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C, commentstyle=\color{green},
backgroundcolor=\color{white}, keywordstyle=\color{blue}, 
basicstyle = \ttfamily \color{black} \footnotesize  } 
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
int main(int argc, char* argv){
int niter=0;
int i,count=0; 
double z,pi,x,y;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i=0; i<niter; i++) {
        x = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        y = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        z = x*x+y*y;
        if (z<=1)
            count++;
    }  
#pragma omp task
    pi=(double)count/niter*4;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome ! please see : http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: This probably has something to do with the font setup, and your code doesn't show anything of that. If I just add `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{xcolor}`, so the code compiles, it also works perfectly fine. So please extend your code to a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: I deleted the following package and it worked. \usepackage{beramono}! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you have

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=C, commentstyle=\color{green},
backgroundcolor=\color{white}, keywordstyle=\color{blue}, 
basicstyle = \ttfamily \color{black} \footnotesize  } 
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[]
int main(int argc, char* argv){
int niter=0;
int i,count=0; 
double z,pi,x,y;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i=0; i<niter; i++) {
        x = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        y = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        z = x*x+y*y;
        if (z<=1)
            count++;
    }  
#pragma omp task
    pi=(double)count/niter*4;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

you get the warning

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/fvm/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `OT1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 9.
```

because the Bera Mono font is only available in T1 encoding. Indeed, the font used for the listing is the default text font, which has different characters in the positions for `_|{}`.

If you don't want to make T1 the default document encoding, you can enable it only for `listings`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=C,
  commentstyle=\color{green},
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}, 
  basicstyle = \fontencoding{T1}\ttfamily \color{black} \footnotesize,
} 

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[]
int main(int argc, char* argv){
int niter=0;
int i,count=0; 
double z,pi,x,y;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i=0; i<niter; i++) {
        x = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        y = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        z = x*x+y*y;
        if (z<=1)
            count++;
    }  
#pragma omp task
    pi=(double)count/niter*4;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

However, you'd have the same problem if you use `\texttt` or `\ttfamily` in other parts of the document, so the simplest workaround is to enable `T1` globally:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
  language=C,
  commentstyle=\color{green},
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue}, 
  basicstyle = \ttfamily \color{black} \footnotesize,
} 

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[]
int main(int argc, char* argv){
int niter=0;
int i,count=0; 
double z,pi,x,y;
#pragma omp parallel for
    for (i=0; i<niter; i++) {
        x = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        y = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX;
        z = x*x+y*y;
        if (z<=1)
            count++;
    }  
#pragma omp task
    pi=(double)count/niter*4;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]